# Drawing a curve (not necessarily an arc) in tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to draw a curve in [`tikz-3dplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot?lang=en) that isn't the arc of a circle. I would like for it to specified by control points, similar to how `tikz` has `(0,0) to [controls=+(45:1) and +(135:1)] (1,0)`. I know I can draw an arc of a circle, with `\tdplotdrawpolytopearc`, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation about how to draw any other type of curve. If I use the same syntax as for 2D curves, it seems a default plane is chosen in which the control points act (seems like the xy-plane). Maybe there's a way to choose that plane (and change it for every point)?

Here's a MWE and output for what I have:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
% Shape and boundary
\draw[blue] (0,0,0)--(-1,1,0);
\fill[green,fill opacity=.8] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--(-1,1,1)--(0,0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--(-1,1,1)--(0,1,1)--(0,0,1)--(0,0,0);
\draw[blue] (0,0,1)--(-1,1,1) (0,1,0)--(0,1,1);
% Natural guess how to draw curve
\draw[red] (0,0,0) to [controls=+(45:1) and +(135:1)] (0,1,0);
% Closest documented way how to draw curve
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,.5,-.3)(0,-.5,.3)(0,1.5,.3)
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc{.583}{}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to draw a curve on the "face" of this prism that's facing left, like the black curve, but with more "strength" at the end points (like a sine curve). The failed attempt is the red curve that seems to be in the plane of the "bottom" face of the prism.

So, my question is: **How can I draw a curve in 3D that is not the arc of a circle?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that the manual of `tikz-3dplot` is not too explicit on this. However, IMHO the main feature of `tikz-3dplot` is to install an orthonormal projection of a 3d coordinate system. Apart from that, you can use the standard Ti*k*Z commands.

In particular, you can use parametric plots to draw anything you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
% Shape and boundary
\draw[blue] (0,0,0)--(-1,1,0);
\fill[green,fill opacity=.8] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--(-1,1,1)--(0,0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--(-1,1,1)--(0,1,1)--(0,0,1)--(0,0,0);
\draw[blue] (0,0,1)--(-1,1,1) (0,1,0)--(0,1,1);
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1] (0,\x,{0.3*sin(\x*180)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in your example you seem to be looking for a way of drawing an ordinary curve on one of the faces. To this end, you only need to use the `3d` library and to draw the curve in the plane that coincides with the corresponding face.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
% Shape and boundary
\draw[blue] (0,0,0)--(-1,1,0);
\fill[green,fill opacity=.8] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--(-1,1,1)--(0,0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--(-1,1,1)--(0,1,1)--(0,0,1)--(0,0,0);
\draw[blue] (0,0,1)--(-1,1,1) (0,1,0)--(0,1,1);
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
    \draw[red] (0,0) to [controls=+(45:1) and +(135:1)] (1,0);
\end{scope}
%\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1] (0,\x,{0.3*sin(\x*180)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

These projections work not only with Ti*k*Z commands but even with external graphics.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
% Shape and boundary
\draw[blue] (0,0,0)--(-1,1,0);
\fill[green,fill opacity=.8] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--(-1,1,1)--(0,0,1);
\draw[blue] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--(-1,1,1)--(0,1,1)--(0,0,1)--(0,0,0);
\draw[blue] (0,0,1)--(-1,1,1) (0,1,0)--(0,1,1);
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=1,transform shape]
    \node at (-0.5,0.5) {\includegraphics[width=0.9cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{scope}
%\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1] (0,\x,{0.3*sin(\x*180)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! This definitely solves my current problem. But I notice the most general answer (the second one) specifies a particular plane - is it possible to draw a curve that is not completely within any one plane (if I don't know its parametric formula)?

Comment: @JānisLazovskis In principle you can do that. However, all the familiar curves use two-dimensional concepts such as `in=angle,out=angle`, `bend=angle` and so on. In 3d you would need more information to define analogous constructions. It can certainly be done but the question is whether users will be comfortable with them. `bend left=alpha` would have to be replaced by `bend in first orthogonal direction by alpha and in the orthogonal direction by beta`. My take is that "guessing" a parametrization for the curve is more efficient.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis However, if you have a set of points in 3d, you can definitely run  smooth curve through them with `\draw plot[smooth] coordinate {(first) (second) ...};`, or possibly with the `hobby` library.